# specific distance between columns of drop down list

Tags: asp.net, linq

i like to have 2 columns in my drop down list with specific distance between 2 columns, so i have added below code but columns are not align with my code.

```
var query = from p in _DataContext.tblDocuments
                    orderby p.DocumentNo

                    select new
                    {
                        Doctitle = p.DocumentNo+' '+' '+"|"+' '+p.TITLE,
                        DocId = p.DocId
                    };
        ddlProjectDocument.DataSource = query;
        ddlProjectDocument.DataValueField = "DocId";
        ddlProjectDocument.DataTextField = "Doctitle";
        ddlProjectDocument.DataBind();
```

please help how i can have 2 columns with normal view and good align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment will depend on the length of the value in the field of your table. One way to do it would be to get the size of the largest entry in your table and make sure that all entries are that wide. Here is something you can try.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStack" runat="server" OnLoad="ddlStack_Load" />
```

and in the source code for ddl load event:

```
  protected void ddlStack_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        var all = from o in _DataContext.tblDocuments
                  orderby o.DocumentNo
                  select o;
        int maxs = 0;
        foreach (tblDocuments v in all)
        {
            if (v.DocumentNo.Length > maxs)
                maxs = v.DocumentNo.Length;
        }



        foreach (tblDocuments vv in all)
        {
            string doctitle = vv.DocumentNo;
            for (int i = vv.DocumentNo.Length; i < maxs + 2; i++)
            {
                doctitle += '_';

            }
            doctitle += " | ";
            doctitle +=  vv.DocID;
            ddlStack.Items.Add(new ListItem(doctitle, vv.vendorID.ToString()));


        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try either from the below two methods:

```
 1). select new
                {
                    Doctitle = p.DocumentNo+" "+"|"+" "+p.TITLE,
                    DocId = p.DocId
                };
```

2).

```
select new
                {
                    Doctitle =Concat(p.DocumentNo,p.TITLE),
                    DocId = p.DocId
                };
```